# Angular material sidebar height issue

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using angular material UI (v10.2.6). I have a side bar and a material table in a component. When the user clicks a button it will open the side bar to display filter options for the table. Everything is working fine but I noticed the height of the sidebar is set by the table height, not the content of the side bar. If a user uses the paginator to show 5 rows on the table, the sidebar is set to the height of the table and the content of the side bar is overflow with a scroll bar. I tried setting fixedInViewport but this is a component inside an existing side bar which is on the root (router outlet) of the application. When I tried it, the top of the side bar disappears under the main application toolbar. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

here is my html:

```
<h2>Assets</h2>
<mat-sidenav-container>
  <mat-sidenav #drawer class="filter-sidenav" mode="side">
    <h3>Filters</h3>
    <mat-divider></mat-divider>
    <mat-toolbar class="button-tool-bar">
      <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="applyFilterOnClick()">Apply</button>
      <span class="spacer"></span>
      <button mat-raised-button (click)="clearFilterOnClick()">Clear</button>
    </mat-toolbar>
    <h4>Districts <span>{{ districtList.selectedOptions.selected.length }}</span></h4>
    <div class="filter-sidenav-list-container">
      <mat-selection-list #districtList>
        <mat-list-option color="primary" value="district.Id" *ngFor="let district of districts">
          {{district.DistrictName}}
        </mat-list-option>
      </mat-selection-list>
    </div>
  </mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content>
    <mat-toolbar class="button-tool-bar">
      <button type="button" title="Main Menu" aria-label="Toggle sidenav" mat-icon-button (click)="drawer.toggle()">
        <mat-icon *ngIf="!drawer.opened" aria-label="Open menu">menu_open</mat-icon>
        <mat-icon *ngIf="drawer.opened" aria-label="Close menu">close</mat-icon>
      </button>
      <mat-form-field class="filter-mat-field">
        <input matInput #searchInput placeholder="Search">
      </mat-form-field>
      <span class="spacer"></span>
      <a mat-raised-button (click)="importOnClick()" *ngIf="currentEmployee.RoleId == roleEnum.Admin">Import Assets</a>
      <a mat-raised-button (click)="addOnClick()" *ngIf="currentEmployee.RoleId == roleEnum.Admin">Add an Asset</a>
    </mat-toolbar>
    <table mat-table class="full-width-table" [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort matSortActive="AssetNumber"
      matSortDirection="asc" matSortDisableClear aria-label="Elements">
      <ng-container matColumnDef="Id">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Id</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.Id}}</td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="AssetNumber">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Asset Number</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.AssetNumber}}</td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="AssetType">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Asset Type</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{ row.AssetTypeName }}</td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="AssetStatus">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Asset Status</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{ row.AssetStatusName }}</td>
      </ng-container>

      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
      <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" (click)="selectRow(row)"
        [ngClass]="{ 'selected': row === selectedRow }"></tr>
    </table>
    <div *ngIf="isLoading" class="loading-spinner">
      <mat-progress-spinner diameter=50 color="primary" mode="indeterminate"></mat-progress-spinner>
    </div>

    <mat-paginator #paginator showFirstLastButtons [length]="dataSource?.assetCount" [pageSize]="pageSize"
      [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 50]">
    </mat-paginator>
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the solution. I had to set the height on the sidebar container as so:

```
mat-sidenav-container {
 height: 100vh;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to take a look at the overflow property.

The overflow CSS shorthand property sets the desired behavior for an element's overflow — i.e. when an element's content is too big to fit in its block formatting context — in both directions.

[Read more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow)

Comment: @steveareeno If it didn't help, please create a sample using https://codesandbox.io/s/angular or https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ru4bng

Comment: Thanks. I haven't set the overflow properties on anything. It appears to be the default behavior of the angular material sidebar. It appears the the side bar container takes it's height from the mat-sidenav-content. I'll see if I can put it in codesandbox